# Zuul cannot connect to Eureka

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I have a Eureka server running ok and a service connecting to it.
Now, I'm trying to connect a Zuul server to Eureka, but it isn't working.
I configure Zuul like this:

```
zuul:
  ignoredServices: "*"
  routes:
    contacts-service: 
      path: /contacts/**
      serviceId: contacts-service

eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka:admin@127.0.0.1:8761/eureka/
```

and my class as

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulServer
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class EdgeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EdgeApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

It never show in eureka neither nothing on the zuul logs eureka-related. Seems like I'm still missing something.

**Edit**

When I changed to `@EnableZuulProxy`, I get an error and the zuul service is still not shown at Eureka server

```
2016-10-06 23:26:46.574  WARN 8303 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter   : Error during filtering

com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:164) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:139) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:84) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112) ~[zuul-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:197) ~[zuul-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:161) ~[zuul-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:120) ~[zuul-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:157) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequestInternal(ZuulController.java:43) [spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
```

**Edit 2**

From time to time, I see this in the eureka server logs (not sure if its related or not to my problem, tho):

```
2016-10-06 23:52:32.824 ERROR 7053 --- [et_localhost-14] c.n.e.cluster.ReplicationTaskProcessor   : Batch update failure with HTTP status code 401; discarding 1 replication tasks
2016-10-06 23:52:32.825  WARN 7053 --- [et_localhost-14] c.n.eureka.util.batcher.TaskExecutors    : Discarding 1 tasks of TaskBatchingWorker-target_localhost-14 due to permanent error
2016-10-06 23:52:38.279  INFO 7053 --- [a-EvictionTimer] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Running the evict task with compensationTime 1ms
```

and *right after* I call the `/contacts/ endpoint, I see this in the zuul proxy logs:

```
2016-10-06 23:52:50.256  INFO 9346 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.n.u.concurrent.ShutdownEnabledTimer    : Shutdown hook installed for: NFLoadBalancer-PingTimer-contacts-service
2016-10-06 23:52:50.309  INFO 9346 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.netflix.loadbalancer.BaseLoadBalancer  : Client:contacts-service instantiated a LoadBalancer:DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=contacts-service,current list of Servers=[],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {},Server stats: []}ServerList:null
2016-10-06 23:52:50.316  INFO 9346 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : Using serverListUpdater PollingServerListUpdater
2016-10-06 23:52:50.322  INFO 9346 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : DynamicServerListLoadBalancer for client contacts-service initialized: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=contacts-service,current list of Servers=[],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {},Server stats: []}ServerList:com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList@29851ac8
2016-10-06 23:52:50.785  WARN 9346 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter   : Error during filtering
```

Comment: What does `/routes` say on the zuul server?

Comment: `{ "/contacts/**": "contacts-service"}`

Comment: If zuul isn't in eureka it won't know how to contact the downstream service. Yes `@EnableZuulProxy` is the right one to use. Any more of the exception?

Comment: @spencergibb just edited with more info

Comment: What is the spring.application.name in the contacts service? That needs to match.

Comment: it is `contacts-service`. the problem is the zuul doesnt register itself in eureka

Comment: Can you share your projects?

Comment: @spencergibb it is on github for some time now: https://github.com/luizkowalski/microservices-netflix-sample

Comment: I won't be able to look until next week.

Comment: No problem. should I ping you someday next week?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing following dependency in your zuul service:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you!!. Also lost a couple of hours searching... Spring magic.

Answer (score 3):

I used this below which works for me.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```